# Mysql select multiple colomn from non related tables

Tags: mysql

I have two table in mysql named rootpath with  only one field 'root' and savecatogory with fields brandid,categoryid,name.There is no relation between these two tables.Now how can retrieve root,brandid,categoryid using single query.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for

```
SELECT rootpath.root, savecatogoroy.brandid, savecatogory.categoryid
FROM rootpath, savecatogoroy
```

Another way is to use the UNION operator, which is well described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

Comment: Thank you.I don't know that this is these much simple

Comment: @Ajith: thats going to give you count(rootpath) * count(savecategory) results--is that really what you want?

Comment: Sure. It will return all combinations. The final list could be filtered using the `WHERE` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need that because

Consider example rootpath has 5 rows
Consider example savecatogoroy has 5 rows

```
SELECT r.root, s.brandid, s.categoryid  FROM rootpath r, savecatogoroy s
```

Then it gives you 5*5 = 25 results

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between these two tables, you just shouldn't try to retrieve it using single query. It is senseless.